# What is the type of the surfaces $x^5 - y^5 + z^2 + x=0$ and $x^5 - y^5 + z^2 + x+1=0$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces

> [This has been answered at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/215122).

I am interested what is the type of the surfaces over the
rationals
$$ x^5 - y^5 + z^2 + x=0$$

and

$$ x^5 - y^5 + z^2 + x+1=0$$

Magma's `KodairaEnriquesType(S : CheckADE:=true);` fails
to compute it.

According to Magma they are not rational.

Partial answers (e.g. it is not $X$) or approaches
how to compute with a CAS are welcome.

Comment: have you tried Wolfram Alpha? try taking $z=+\sqrt{y^5-x^5-x}$ to start with

Comment: @DavidQuinn No. What is the function for surface classification?

Comment: A small comment: you can easily see by hand that this thing does not have ADE singularities. Indeed, its projectivisation $x^5-y^5+z^2t^3+xt^4$ has one singular point, at $x=y=t=0$, and this is a triple point, whereas ADE singularities are _double_ points.

Comment: Anyway, these questions seem surprisingly difficult and frustrating. I guess there is no slick way to do this for arbitrary singular surfaces --- if there was, it would probably already be implemented in computer algebra!

Comment: @Relapsarian Thanks. This well might be a Magma bug, do you need exact code for Magma Online? This might be not be implemented in Magma yet and the documentation to be not entirely correct.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean: what might be a bug? The singularity is not ADE, so I would expect the computation should fail, as I thought you described in the question.

Comment: @Relapsarian On related MO question, someone suggested to do desingularization, but Magma appear to have problems in such singularities too...

Comment: @Relapsarian RE ADE, ok, likely I misunderstood, never mind. The computation indeed fails for me.

Comment: Cross-posted on MO:  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/215122/what-is-the-type-of-the-surfaces-x5-y5-z2-x-0-and-x5-y5-z2